# import contacts Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment

Tags: import, error

I am using Drupal 7.50 and Civicrm 4.7.11 and received  Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
I am trying to import from a csv, individual records, 200 at a time. I imported the 1st lot ok but when i tried the 2nd it failed so I tried the 3rd with backtrace error logging.

my backtrace shows: (I have replaced "mysite")

backTrace

```
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_nume...")
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, (Array:2), "SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_nume...")
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_nume...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1728 ** Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted")
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_nume...")
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2438): DB_common->query("SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_nume...")
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1627): DB_DataObject->_query("SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_nume...")
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(344): DB_DataObject->query("SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_nume...")
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1265): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_nume...", TRUE)
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1963): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_nume...")
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Phone.php(74): CRM_Core_DAO::checkSqlFunctionsExist()
#15 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Block.php(348): CRM_Core_BAO_Phone::add((Array:6))
#16 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Location.php(66): CRM_Core_BAO_Block::create("phone", (Array:20), NULL)
#17 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(348): CRM_Core_BAO_Location::create((Array:20), TRUE)
#18 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php(1897): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::create((Array:20))
#19 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php(1696): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::createProfileContact((Array:7), (Array:35), NULL, NULL, NULL, "Individual")
#20 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php(675): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser_Contact->createContact((Array:7), (Array:35), "16", NULL, TRUE, "")
#21 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser.php(217): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser_Contact->import("16", (Array:23), NULL)
#22 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/ImportJob.php(302): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser->run("civicrm_import_job_8a23b4cabd18fd2738229c5c5b770bf2", (Array:20), 8, 1, "_id", "_status", "16", "fdf1658839c381797efed4e50ff5faaf", 200, NULL, 30, NULL, "")
#23 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Form/Preview.php(305): CRM_Contact_Import_ImportJob->runImport(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview))
#24 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(423): CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview->postProcess()
#25 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#26 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview), "next", "Next")
#27 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview), "next")
#28 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview), "next")
#29 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#30 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#31 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#32 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#33 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#34 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("import", "contact")
#35 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#36 /home/mysite/public_html/drupal/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#37 {main}
 Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
DB Error: unknown error
Error Details
Return to home page.
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a permissions issue, if you try to login to the database and run the command that its trying to run i.e. SHOW function status WHERE db = database() AND name = 'civicrm_strip_non_numeric', see if that works for you as the same user that CiviCRM logs in as.